# How to check parent access in an array tree?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, treeview

I have an infinite array tree:

```
type Test = {
  id: string;
  hasAccess: Boolean;
  access: 'None' | 'View';
  children: Test[];
};

const Data: Test[] = [
  {
    id: '1',
    access: 'View',
    children: [
      {
        id: '2.1',
        access: 'None',
        children: [
          {
            id: '3.1',
            access: 'None',
            children: [
              { id: '4.1', access: 'None', children: [] },
              { id: '4.2', access: 'None', children: [] },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '2.2',
        access: 'View',
        children: [
          {
            id: '3.2',
            access: 'View',
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

What I want to do is check the current access against the parent's access - unless there is a way to check the children's access in an array tree.

So if I'm at id: '2.1', I'm checking my access against id: '1'.

The rules are, if my access === 'View', then my hasAccess boolean will be true. If my access === 'None' but my parent's access === "View", my access will also be true.

It's only if my access === "None" and my parent's access === "None" that my hasAccess boolean will be false.

I have a recursion function. But it's not working as I expect.

```
const setParent = (Data, parentAccess) => ({
  ...Data,
  // checking condition here
  hasAccess: parentAccess === 'None' && Data.access === 'None' && false || true,
});

const setData = (Data: any[]) => {
  if (Data.length) {
    if (Data[0].children.length) {
      const currentAccess = Data[0].access;
      Data[0] = Data[0].children.map((data) => setParent(data, currentAccess));
    } else {
      Data.forEach(({ children }) => setData(children));
    }
  }
};
```

This is my expected output:

```
// id: '2.1' hasAccess: true because it's parent access === "View".
// id: '3.1' hasAccess: false because it's access === "None" and it's parent's access === "None".
// And all of id: '3.1' children hasAccess will be false.
const DataAfter: Test[] = [
  {
    id: '1',
    hasAccess: true,
    access: 'View',
    children: [
      {
        id: '2.1',
        hasAccess: true,
        access: 'None',
        children: [
          {
            id: '3.1',
            hasAccess: false,
            access: 'None',
            children: [
              { id: '4.1', hasAccess: false, access: 'None', children: [] },
              { id: '4.2', hasAccess: false, access: 'None', children: [] },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '2.2',
        hasAccess: true,
        access: 'View',
        children: [
          {
            id: '3.2',
            hasAccess: true,
            access: 'View',
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `hasAccess: parentAccess === 'None' && Data.access === 'None' && false || true,` will always return `true`. You can use ternary operator to fix that.

Also, in the recursive method, you are only setting hasAccess for all the children of the first array item. For other items and you are not setting parent.

You can do the following,

```js
const Data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    access: 'View',
    children: [
      {
        id: '2.1',
        access: 'None',
        children: [
          {
            id: '3.1',
            access: 'None',
            children: [
              { id: '4.1', access: 'None', children: [] },
              { id: '4.2', access: 'None', children: [] },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '2.2',
        access: 'View',
        children: [
          {
            id: '3.2',
            access: 'View',
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];


const setParent = (Data, parentAccess) => {
  return {
    hasAccess: parentAccess === 'None' && Data.access === 'None' ? false : true,
    ...Data,
  };
};

const setData = (dataItem, parentAccess = 'None') => {
      
      if(dataItem.children.length) {
        const currentAccess = dataItem.access;
        dataItem.children = dataItem.children.map(child => setData(child, currentAccess));
      } 
      
      dataItem = setParent(dataItem, parentAccess);
      return dataItem;
};
newData = Data.map(dataItem => setData(dataItem, dataItem.access))
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Ohh I see,  I'm pretty new to recursions. Thank you so much Sabbir. I'll give that a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly simply in a single function:

```js
const setAccess = (xs, parent = null) =>
  xs .map (({id, access, children = []}) => ({
    id,
    hasAccess: (access != 'None' || (parent != null && parent != 'None')),
    access,
    children: setAccess (children, access)
  }))

const Data = [{id: '1', access: 'View', children: [{id: '2.1', access: 'None', children: [{id: '3.1', access: 'None', children: [{id: '4.1', access: 'None', children: []}, {id: '4.2', access: 'None', children: []}]}]}, {id: '2.2', access: 'View', children: [{id: '3.2', access: 'View', children: []}]}]}];

console .log (setAccess (Data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The only complexity has to do with handling the root nodes, which don't have a parent.  We default the parent access to `null` and replace the obvious `(access != 'None' || parent != 'None')` with `(access != 'None' || (parent != null && parent != 'None'))`, making the recursion quite simple.